# Mixfdr penalization parameter

Tags: multiple-comparisons, p-value

I'm trying to use mixfdr in a simulation of p-values but sometimes the search for the penalization parameter spits out an error and shows some matrix entries to be infinite:

```
>m <- mixFdr(stdjk,plots=F,J=3,theonull=F,calibrate=T)
Fitting preliminary model 
[1] 0.750 0.125 0.125
[1] -7412.522 -7412.522 -7412.522
[1] 3706.261 3706.261 3706.261
[,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.750 -7412.522 3706.261
[2,] 0.125 -7412.522 3706.261
[3,] 0.125 -7412.522 3706.261
[,1] [,2]
[1,] -Inf  Inf
[2,] -Inf  Inf
[3,] -Inf  Inf
 [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.1  Inf
[2,]  0.1  Inf
[3,]  0.1  Inf
Error in if (distance < tol) converged = TRUE : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is this normal or am i missing some parameter?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Try contacting the package author.

Answer (score 1):

This is just saying that the algorithm has failed to converge.  I had the same problem and increasing the `maxIter` argument from the default 1000 to 2000 solved it for me.

You might also play with the `tol` argument.  If none of that works you should consider the possibility that your data are not well described by the model.